# Jquery Tabs Link Inside Content to Reload wit Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, hyperlink, tabs

I'm looking for a answer for this issue for days.

I have some UI Tabs with Jquery. When I click in a tab, the content is load. Inside this content I need links, like ordination links, which I need to reload the content with Ajax.

BUT, the link is reload outside the tabs, like a normal link.

In the Jsfiddle below I could not load correctly the file links because I dont know the JSfiddle very well.

In the demo below, the link that a need to work, is the "Teste" inside "30ml" Tab.

[Demo](http://sencial.me/teste_tabs/teste_tabs_fiddle.html)

Please, what is the correct code to load correctly this links through Ajax?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vp4w86s7/)

```
<div id='tabs'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='http://sencial.me/teste_tabs/teste_tabs_fiddle_30ml_1.html'>30ml (3)</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://sencial.me/teste_tabs/teste_tabs_fiddle_50ml_1.html'>50ml (3)</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
          ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });

      }
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

After load a content of a tab, you can try execute this code to get all `a` links and load the content inside the tab. Also, adapt to your necessity.

```
$('#ui-id-2 a').each(function () {
  $(this).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).load($(this).attr('href'));
  })
});
```

Comment: Hi! Tks, but unfortunately didn't work! The #ui-id-2 is the id from DIV where the content need to be loaded right?!

Comment: Yes. and as I said you can change to your purpose. I only change the click on links to do another `load()` ajax request, overriding the content. Sorry if I miss understand something.

Comment: Please, can you test at this [example](http://sencial.me/teste_tabs/teste_tabs_fiddle.html) (link Teste)? My javascript understanding is very low.

Comment: Just one more thing: do you know how can I get the DIV id (ui-id-2), once Jquery generate dynamically?

Comment: You can select generated divs by select div one level inside `#tabs` as `$("#tabs > div")`. If it's helps please, make my comment up. @Ailton